# I want to get folders without recursion

Tags: c#

I want to get folders without recursion and print it to stdout.
I have code using recursion.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    WriteDirectories(@"C:\Intel");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void WriteDirectories(string path) {
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path/*, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories*/);

    for(int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++) {
        Console.WriteLine(dirs[i]);
        WriteDirectories(dirs[i]);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me to get folders without using recursively?

in this code I get all folders which are in testfolder. in testfolder3 is one folder, I can not get it.

```
static void WriteDirectories(string path)
        {
            string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path/*, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories*/);
            for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(dirs[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < dirs[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    break;
                    
                        string[] dirs1 = Directory.GetDirectories(dirs[i]);
                        Console.WriteLine(" " + dirs1[j]);  
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why? it's true that every recursive process can be translated to a non-recursive process, but it's usually harder to write and maintain.

Comment: What does ` i can not get it.` mean? It is missing from the final result? Throws an exception related to access rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get all subdirectories without using a recursive function, you can use a Stack where you maintain items that need to be searched:

```
static void WriteDirectoriesInternal(Stack<string> stack)
{
    while (stack.Count > 0)
    {
        var currDir = stack.Pop();
        Console.WriteLine(currDir);

        foreach (var item in Directory.GetDirectories(currDir))
            stack.Push(item);
    }
}

static void WriteDirectories(string path)
{
    Stack<string> directoryStack = new Stack<string>();
    directoryStack.Push(path);
    WriteDirectoriesInternal(directoryStack);
}

public static void Main(String[] args)
{
    WriteDirectories("D:\\Program Files (x86)");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: in this code i get all folders wich is in testfolder. in testfolder3 is one folder, i can not get it.

Comment: Yes,  it fails for folders that you are not allowed to read. Like some folders within Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling `WriteDirectories` inside your for loop.

You need to remove the line `WriteDirectores(dirs[i]);`.

Comment: yes but task is that not must use indirect recursion and parameter SearchOption.AllDirectories

Answer (score 0):

You find a solution in this [MSDN-arcticle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd383462(v=vs.110).aspx)

The trick is to use the SearchOption.AllDirectories enumeration value as last parameter

Comment: yes but task is that not must use indirect recursion and  parameter   SearchOption.AllDirectories